# Binomial expansion for noncommutative operator

Tags: noncommutative-algebra, binomial-coefficients

Is it possible to find a closed formula for $(A^\dagger -kA)^n$ with $[A,A^\dagger]=1$ ?

I am looking for the normal ordinate form: $\sum (A)^{n-j}(A^\dagger)^j$— possibly something to do with the commutator, I don't know.

Comment: And what is $A^{\dagger}$? Moore-Penrose inverse (this is what the dagger often means, although probably not here)?

Comment: What does the bracket mean? Is it the commutator?Also we are missing the binomial coefficients.

Comment: It is the raising operator in quantum mechanics, it takes the state n to n+1. 
Yes, the commutator is equal to 1.

Comment: You will not get an answer in the exact form you specify; the sum of the powers will not necessarily be $n$, as the corresponding algebra is filtered, not graded. Even for $n = 2$, you get:

$(A^\dagger - kA)^2 = A^{\dagger 2} - k A^\dagger A - k A A^\dagger + k^2 A^2 = A^{\dagger 2} - 2 k A^\dagger A - k + k^2 A^2$

Which has a term of lower degree (the -k). You'll need to sum over lower degrees.

Answer (score 3):

As I said in the above comment, you will not get an answer in the exact form you specify; the sum of the powers will not necessarily be $n$, as the corresponding algebra is filtered, not graded. Even for $n = 2$, you get:

$(A^\dagger - kA)^2 = A^{\dagger 2} - k A^\dagger A - k A A^\dagger + k^2 A^2 = A^{\dagger 2} - 2 k A^\dagger A - k + k^2 A^2$

In order to get the answer:

First, we need to find $[A^\dagger, (A^\dagger - kA)^n]$; induction (or Leibniz rule) shows that it will equal $n(A^\dagger - kA)^{n - 1}$.

Then: $(A^\dagger - kA)^{n+1} = (A^\dagger - kA)^n(A^\dagger - kA)$

$ = A^\dagger (A^\dagger - kA)^n - k (A^\dagger - kA)^n A - [A^\dagger, (A^\dagger - kA)^n]$

$ = A^\dagger (A^\dagger - kA)^n - k (A^\dagger - kA)^n A - n(A^\dagger - kA)^{n - 1}$

If both the $(A^\dagger - kA)^i$ are well-ordered (with $A^\dagger$ in front and $A$ in back), then this expression for $(A^\dagger - kA)^{n + 1}$ is too, so we have our recursion relation.

Some induction then shows that:

$(A^\dagger - kA)^n = \sum_{i = 0}^n (-k)^i a_{n, i} \sum_{j = 0}^{n - i} {{n - i}\choose{j}} A^{\dagger j} (-k)^{n - i - j} A^{n - i - j}$

where $a_{n, i} = 0$ if $i$ is odd, and $\frac{n!}{(n - i)! i!!}$ if $i$ is even, where $i!!$ denotes the double factorial $i!! = 2*4*6*...*i = 2^{\frac{i}{2}} (\frac{i}{2})!$

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain what you would like to find. See if this paper and its references

> Tewodros Amdeberhan, Valerio De Angelis, Atul Dixit, Victor H. Moll and Christophe Vignat, *From sequences to polynomials and back, via operator orderings*
>   Journal of Mathematical Physics **54** (2013) 123502, doi:[10.1063/1.4836778](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.4836778), arXiv:[1303.6587](https://arxiv.org/abs/1303.6587) ([pdf](http://dauns.math.tulane.edu/~vhm/papers_html/ordering1.pdf))

would help you in any way.